# Showing a list of corresponding labels for ggplotly hover

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, r-plotly, ggplotly

I want to display information from a dataframe in an interactive box plot. The corresponding code is:

```
p=ggplot(data = data,
       aes(x = GeoAreaName,  fill= cat, text= Indicator)) +
  geom_bar()

ggplotly(p)
```

"cat" is a categorical variable describing data quality, "GeoAreaName" is a country name and "Indicator" is the data set name that "cat" describes.

The result I get is almost what I want:
[image: ggplotly result]

However, I want to have the labels of  the Indicator only shown when I hover above it, i.e. a list of names corresponding to the categories "cat" should appear, not every single one as its own segment in the bar plot.

Any suggestions?

Edit: Excerpt of the data:
[image: data]

Comment: Can you add an example of your data? It seems as if `text` is far more granular than what you want to plot.

Comment: @c0bra added a part of the data frame

Comment: For Azerbaijan, ggplot needs to plot at least two different `indiacator`s per `cat`. If you aggregate the `indicator` beforehand it should be fine.

Comment: Also it is always preferred to put example data with `dput` on SO.

Comment: @c0bra Thanks for your comment, I don't use stackoverflow regularly so I am not yet familiar with preferred styles. How would I aggregate the data beforehand?

Comment: Try `data %>% group_by(GeoAreaName, cat) %>% summarize(Indicator = paste(Indicator, collapse=", ")`. Not sure if this is your intention about the data visualization.

Comment: One correction: `dataNew = data %>% group_by(GeoAreaName, cat) %>% summarize(Indicator = paste(Indicator, collapse=", "), count=n())`
Plot with `ggplot(data = data, aes(x = GeoAreaName, y=count, fill= cat, text= Indicator)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate the indicator by concatenation.

```
dataNew <- data %>% 
    group_by(GeoAreaName, cat) %>%
    summarize(Indicator = paste(Indicator, collapse=", "), count=n())
```

Plotting:

```
p <- ggplot(data = dataNew, aes(x = GeoAreaName, y=count, fill= cat, text= Indicator)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity")
```